# Where do I learn "what I need to know" about C++ compilers?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

I'm just starting to explore C++, so forgive the newbiness of this question.  I also beg your indulgence on how open ended this question is.  I think it could be broken down, but I think that this information belongs in the same place.

(FYI -- I am working predominantly with the QT SDK and mingw32-make right now and I seem to have configured them correctly for my machine.)

I knew that there was a lot in the language which is compiler-driven -- I've heard about pre-compiler directives, but it seems like someone would be able to write books the different C++ compilers and their respective parameters.  In addition, there are commands which apparently precede make (like qmake, for example (is this something only in QT)).

I would like to know if there is any place which gives me an overview of what compilers are out there, and what their different options are.  I'd also like to know how each of them views Makefiles (it seems that there is a difference in syntax between them?).

If there is no website regarding, "Everything you need to know about C++ compilers but were afraid to ask," what would be the best way to go about learning the answers to these questions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Concerning the "numerous options of the various compilers"**
A piece of good news: you needn't worry about the detail of most of these options.  You will, in due time, delve into this, only for the very compiler you use, and maybe only for the options that pertain to a particular set of features.  But as a novice, generally trust the default options or the ones supplied with the make files.

The broad categories of these features (and I may be missing a few) are:

- pre-processor defines (now, you may need a few of these)
- code generation (target CPU, FPU usage...)
- optimization  (hints for the compiler to favor speed over size and such)
- inclusion of debug info (which is extra data left in the object/binary and which enables the debugger to know where each line of code starts, what the variables names are etc.)
- directives for the linker
- output type (exe, library, memory maps...)
- C/C++ language compliance and warnings  (compatibility with previous version of the compiler, compliance to current and past  C Standards,  warning about common possible bug-indicative patterns...)
- compile-time verbosity and help

**Concerning an inventory of compilers with their options and features**
I know of no such list but I'm sure it probably exists on the web.  However, suggest that, as a novice you worry little about these "details", and use whatever free compiler you can find (gcc certainly a great choice), and build experience with the language and the build process. C professionals may likely argue, with good reason and at length on the merits of various compilers and associated runtine etc., but for generic purposes -and then some- the free stuff is all that is needed.

**Concerning the build process**
The most trivial applications, such these made of a single unit of compilation (read a single C/C++ source file),  can be built with a simple batch file where the various compiler and linker options are hardcoded, and where the name of file is specified on the command line.
For all other cases, it **is very important to codify the build process** so that it can be done 
   a) automatically and
   b) reliably, i.e. with repeatability.
The "recipe" associated with this build process is often encapsulated in **a make file** or as the complexity grows, possibly several make files, possibly "bundled together in a script/bat file.
This (make file syntax) you need to get familiar with, even if you use alternatives to make/nmake, such as Apache Ant; the reason is that many (most?) source code packages include a make file.
**In a nutshell**, make files are text files and they allow defining *targets*, and the associated *command* to build a target.  Each target is associated with its *dependencies*, which allows the make logic to decide what targets are out of date and should be rebuilt, and, before rebuilding them, what possibly dependencies should also be rebuilt.  That way, when you modify say an include file (and if the make file is properly configured) any c file that used this header will be recompiled and any binary which links with the corresponding obj file will be rebuilt as well.  make also include options to force all targets to be rebuilt, and this is sometimes handy to be sure that you truly have a current built (for example in the case some dependencies of a given object are not declared in the make).

**On the Pre-processor**:
The pre-processor is the first step toward compiling, although it is technically not part of the compilation.  The purposes of this step are:

- to remove any comment, and extraneous whitespace
- to substitute any macro reference with the relevant C/C++ syntax.  Some macros for example are used to define constant values such as say some email address used in the program; during per-processing any reference to this constant value (btw by convention such constants are named with `ALL_CAPS_AND_UNDERSCORES`) is replace by the actual C string literal containing the email address.
- to exclude all conditional compiling branches that are not relevant  (the #IFDEF and the like)

What's important to know about the pre-processor is that the pre-processor directive are NOT part of the C-Language proper, and they serve several important functions such as the conditional compiling mentionned earlier (used for example to have multiple versions of the program, say for different Operating Systems, or indeed for different compilers)

**Taking it from there...**
After this manifesto of mine... I encourage to read but little more, and to dive into programming and building binaries.  `It is a very good idea to try and get a broad picture of the framework etc. but this can be overdone`, a bit akin to the exchange student who stays in his/her room reading the Webster dictionary to be "prepared" for meeting native speakers, rather than just "doing it!".

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you shouldn't need to care what C++ compiler you are using. The compatability to the standard has got much better in recent years (even from microsoft)

Compiler flags obviously differ but the same features are generally available, it's just a differently named option to eg.  set warning level on GCC and ms-cl

The build system is indepenant of the compiler, you can use any make with any compiler.

Answer (score 3):

That *is* a lot of questions in one.

`C++` compilers are a lot like hammers:  They come in all sizes and shapes, with different abilities and features, intended for different types of users, and at different price points; ultimately they all are for doing the same basic task as the others.

Some are intended for highly specialized applications, like high-performance graphics, and have  numerous extensions and libraries to assist the engineer with those types of problems.  Others are meant for general purpose use, and aren't necessarily always the greatest for extreme work.

The technique for using each type of hammer varies from model to model—and version to version—but they all have a lot in common.  The macro preprocessor is a standard part of C and C++ compilers.

A brief comparison of many `C++` compilers is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers#C.2FC.2B.2B_compilers).  Also check out the list of `C` compilers, since many programs don't use any C++ features and can be compiled by ordinary `C`.

---

`C++` compilers don't "view" makefiles.  The rules of a makefile may invoke a C++ compiler, but also may "compile" assembly language modules (*assembling*), process other languages, build libraries, link modules, and/or post-process object modules.  Makefiles often contain rules for cleaning up intermediate files, establishing debug environments, obtaining source code, etc., etc.  Compilation is one link in a long chain of steps to develop software.

Also, many development environments abstract the makefile into a "project file" which is used by an [integrated development environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) (IDE) in an attempt to simplify or automate many programming tasks.  See a comparison [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments).

As for learning:  choose a specific problem to solve and dive in.  The target platform (Linux/Windows/etc.) and problem space will narrow the choices pretty well.  Which you choose is often linked to other considerations, such as working for a particular company, or being part of a team.  C++ has something like 95% commonality among all its flavors.  Learn any one of them well, and learning the next is a piece of cake.